# How to get XML response from PowerShell New-WebServiceProxy

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell, soap, wsdl

So PowerShell is great that it auto generates strongly typed classes when using `New-WebServiceProxy` with a `WSDL`. I'm perfectly able to talk to the webservice, but I actually **want the response XML** not the response object (strongly typed).

Following example code:

```
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://internal/EmployeeDetails?WSDL
$gpr = new-object "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1S_EmployeeDetails_WSDL.GetEmployeeRequestType"
$req.USERID = "U015412"
$req.clientID = "12345"
$person = $proxy.getEmployee($req)
$person.Person | select * | Format-List

#OUTPUT:
#Name : Smith
#FirstName : John
```

`$person` is a `GetEmployeeResponseType` and I can't see any methods like GetXML or something like that. I found a similar topic here: [How can I view the SOAP/XML that my web service proxy class is sending?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1434488.aspx?How%20can%20I%20view%20the%20SOAP%20XML%20that%20my%20web%20service%20proxy%20class%20is%20sending%20), but I am not sure how I would intercept the call via PowerShell and if there isn't a better method. I also sometimes see people suggesting *use Fiddler*... I want the returned XML in PowerShell, so that i can export it to a file. `Export-Clixml` also doesn't do the trick as the PS object is exported, not the **raw reponse XML**.